# Convert Kinetic textPath to image

Tags: kineticjs

I am using following code to convert kinetic textPath to image

```
        var simpleText = new Kinetic.TextPath({
        x: 400,
        y: 0,
        fill: '#333',
        fontSize: '24',
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        text: 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum ',
        data: 'M70,70 A50,50 0 1,1 69,70'
      });

      var textImgSrc = simpleText.toDataURL(); // base64 image of text
      var textImgObj = new Image();
      textImgObj.src = textImgSrc; 
      console.log(textImgObj.src);
```

but in console it gives me no image else "data:,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set position and size properties for your `TextPath`:

```
var textImgSrc = simpleText.toDataURL({
    x : 0,
    y : 50,
    width : 130,
    height : 130
}); // base64 image of text
```

http://jsbin.com/newuro/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you please look into this also: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735789/convert-line-to-image-in-kinetic-js-v5-0-0 .  Thanks in advance